# How do I make an existing C# library UWP-compatible?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a simple data structure published to NuGet that's semi-popular.  It doesn't use any special Windows APIs, so I would expect it to be already compatible with UWP.

However, when people try to add a reference through NuGet, they see

> <Project> is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
>   Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.

**What do I need to do to make my project compatible with UWP** *(while still keeping compatibility with non-UWP projects, including .Net 2.0 support)*?  I've read answers online ranging from *"add this .json file"* to *"you need to maintain an entirely separate project"*!

Comment: So you want to have just one dll\project which is compatible with all target frameworks? Because if not you can just put several dlls targeting different frameworks in one nuget package, and correct one will be chosen when user installs your package.

Comment: @Evk: Can I do that with different project configurations?  Or do I need separate projects?  In either case, how do I do that?  I've never done anything with UWP before, and trying to search for tutorials for writing UWP-compatible libraries, it seems absurdly unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I prefer to use source code sharing, because things like PCL has too many restrictions. You just create UWP library project in visual studio, add all files from your .NET project as links (so you have single codebase) and compile that UWP project. Of course it won't be that easy, in that case you can use conditional compilation symbols (#if WINDOWS_UWP // UWP-specific code #else // non-UWP code). You can also use visual studio Shared Project feature. It's close to adding files as links as described above, but more convenient. Then you pack both into one nuget package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several approaches right now,

1. Write a PCL which enables UWP compatibility.
2. Write a UWP class library which links to the common source files.
3. Migrate the library to .NET Core.

I use the last for my open source library and the blog post covers the details,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/03/how-to-port-snmp-library-to-net-core/

Comment: Do any of these options keep compatibility with non-UWP projects?  I think #2, at least, breaks it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft all approaches I listed require you to create new class library projects. #1 and #3 allow you to use the new class library for both UWP and non-UWP projects, while #2 requires you to use the old class library for non-UWP projects, while the new for UWP ones.

Comment: However, #3 won't work with .net 2 as far as I know. Not sure about pcl.

Comment: @Liero I rather say none of them works well for .NET 2.0. I will be surprised if any serious developer still targets that old platform.

Comment: .net 3.5 uses .net 2 runtime. Sharepoint 2010 is still running in many companies. It requires .net 3.5. However, he can build separate assemblies for .net 2 and .net core (or pcl) and put the to single nuget package, so it will be consumable from everywhere